# Repeat values in a list (having two list) in python

Tags: python, list

I'm coding in Python, I have an exercise like this :

```
long = [5, 2, 4]
number = [1, 2, 3]
ids = []
```

I want to have :

```
ids = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I want to repeat 5 times 1, 2 times 2, 4 times 3.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Not even trying? I'm not sure where I should start with the explanation. Do you know what a `for` loop is?

Comment: Yes I know Python (for loop, while, everything). But I don't know how to solve this

Comment: You will surely get a solution here. But `coding in Python` includes attempts and errors which is mainly the path to be a good programmer in the end. Not posting the exercise on a forum and looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Just try to code something, to have a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

long = [5, 2, 4]
number = [1, 2, 3]

ids = list(Counter(dict(zip(number, long))).elements())
print(ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple loop which will iterate over `(times-to-repeat, number)` pairs and extend your output list with generated list of numbers :

```
for times, n in zip(long, number):
    ids.extend([n] * times) 
print(ids) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

They've provided you with two very good solutions, but I'll leave the brute force approach (hardly ever the best one) in here, since it's the one you're likely more prone to understand:

```
long = [5, 2, 4]
number = [1, 2, 3]
ids = []

for i in range(len(long)):
    aux = 0
    while (aux < long[i]):
        ids.append(number[i])
        aux += 1
print(ids)
```